# String replace with condition

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have two pandas dataframes. One contains text, the other a set of terms i'd like to search for and replace within the text. I have a method to do this, however I would like to add conditions. The conditions are, if the term contains the word either 'no' or 'none' up to three words before, to not replace.

In the example below ID 2 is incorrectly replaced based on the conditions above.

Example text:

```
d = {'ID': [1, 2, 3], 'Text': ['here is some random text', 'no such random text, none here', 'more random text']}
text_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Example terms:

```
d = {'Replace_item': ['<RANDOM_REPLACED>', '<HERE_REPLACED>', '<SOME_REPLACED>'], 'Text': ['random', 'here', 'some']}
replace_terms_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Method for replacing terms (with ID 2 being incorrect based on conditions):

```
text_df['Text'] = [z.replace(x, y) for (x, y, z) in zip(replace_terms_df.Text, replace_terms_df.Replace_item, text_df.Text)]
```

Target dataframe (considering the conditions):

```
d = {'ID': [1, 2, 3], 'Text': ['<HERE_REPLACED> is <SOME_REPLACED> <RANDOM_REPLACED> text', 'no such random text, none here', 'more  <RANDOM_REPLACED> text']}
target_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Please ask if you need clarity. Thank you.

Comment: You're only replacing `'random'` in the first row, `'here'` in the second row and `'some'` in the third row. Is this expected, or do you want to replace the replacement items on EVERY row?

Comment: The condition should allow strings to be replaced, providing ‘not’ or ‘none’ are not within three words of the replacement term. In the case of ID 2, there is a ‘not’ and a ‘none’ within three words of the term so they shouldn’t be replaced. My example isn’t working and is just replacing - this is what I’d like help with :)

Comment: But I still don't understand your desired output, With your above code the output for the first line is `'here is some <RANDOM_REPLACED> text'` You want that instead of `'<HERE_REPLACED> is <SOME_REPLACED> <RANDOM_REPLACED> text'`? If you really want the first, why do you have two separate dataframes? Shouldn't this information just be in one? There's no linking ID between the two `df`s them other than the row index, which isn't always intentional.

Comment: I've added an example of my target dataframe in my question for you. I hope this provides clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following code with regex solution:

```
import re

# set up the regex pattern
# the words which should be skipped, must be whole word and case-insensitive
ptn_to_skip = re.compile(r'\b(?:no|none)\b', re.IGNORECASE)

# the pattern for mapping
# Note: any regex meta charaters need to be escaped, or it will fail.
ptn_to_map = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(replace_terms_df.Text.tolist()) + r')\b')

# map from text to Replace_item
terms_map = replace_terms_df.set_index('Text').Replace_item

def adjust_text(x):
    # if 1 - 3 ptn_to_skip found, return x, 
    # otherwise, map the matched group \1 with terms_map
    if 0 < len(ptn_to_skip.findall(x)) <= 3:
        return x
    else:
        return ptn_to_map.sub(lambda y: terms_map[y.group(1)], x)

# do the conversion:
text_df['new_text'] = text_df.Text.apply(adjust_text)
```

**Some Notes:**

- I converted the texts in `replace_terms_df.Text` into a regex. default the texts are all plain-text without regex meta characters.
- if there are any regex meta characters like '$', ']' etc, you will have to escape them. regex tends to be slow especially with meta characters, if you have large chuck of data, don't suggest this solution to you.

**Update:**

A new logic is added to check the excluded-words ['no', 'none'] first, if matches, then find the next 0-3 words which are not themselves excluded-words, save them to \1, the actual matched search-word will be saved in \2. then in the regex replacement part, handle them differently.

Below are the new code:

```
import re

# pattern to excluded words (must match whole-word and case insensitive)
ptn_to_excluded = r'\b(?i:no|none)\b'

# ptn_1 to match the excluded-words ['no', 'none'] and the following maximal 3 words which are not excluded-words
# print(ptn_1)  -->    \b(?i:no|none)\b\s*(?:(?!\b(?i:no|none)\b)\S+\s*){,3}
# where (?:(?!\b(?i:no|none)\b)\S+\s*) matches any words '\S+' which is not in ['no', 'none'] followed by optional white-spaces
# {,3} to specify matches up to 3 words 
ptn_1 = r'{0}\s*(?:(?!{0})\S+\s*){{,3}}'.format(ptn_to_excluded)

# ptn_2 is the list of words you want to convert with your terms_map
# print(ptn_2)    -->    \b(?:random|here|some)\b
ptn_2 = r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(replace_terms_df.Text.tolist()) + r')\b'

# new pattern based on the alternation using ptn_1 and ptn_2
# regex:  (ptn_1)|(ptn_2)
new_ptn = re.compile('({})|({})'.format(ptn_1, ptn_2))

# map from text to Replace_item
terms_map = replace_terms_df.set_index('Text').Replace_item

# regex function to do the convertion
def adjust_map(x):
    return new_ptn.sub(lambda m:  m.group(1) or terms_map[m.group(2)], x)

# do the conversion:
text_df['new_text'] = text_df.Text.apply(adjust_map)
```

**Explanation:**

I defined two sub-patterns:

- ptn_1: try to match the words you want to be excluded, i.e., the words 'no', 'none' followed by at most 3 more words which are not in ['no', 'none']
- ptn_2: try to match one of the words you want to convert based on the replace_terms_df.

How it works:

- with the alternation '|', the regex engine will make sure ptn_1 matches before ptn_2, if neither matches, the original text is kept.
- The matched ptn_1 text will be saved in m.group(1) and ptn_2 result to m.group(2)
- In the replacement part. If m.group(1) is not Empty(meaning ptn_1 is matched) then return m.group(1) (thus this part of matches is untouched), otherwise return terms_map[y.group(2)]

**Some tests below:**

```
In []: print(new_ptn)
re.compile('(\\b(?i:no|none)\\b\\s*(?:(?!\\b(?i:no|none)\\b)\\S+\\s*){,3})|(\\b(random|here|some)\\b)')

In[]: for i in [
    'yes, no such a random text'
  , 'yes, no such a a random text'
  , 'no no no such a random text no such here here here no'
 ]: print('{}:\n  [{}]'.format(i, adjust_map(i)))
...:
yes, no such a random text:
  [yes, no such a random text]
yes, no such a a random text:
  [yes, no such a a <RANDOM_REPLACED> text]
no no no such a random text no such here here here no:
  [no no no such a random text no such here here <HERE_REPLACED> no]
```

Let me know if this works.

**More to consider:**

- in ptn_1, '\S+' is used to define a WORD, this will have issue if one of the words is something like '**,none**', this preceding 'comma' will let it skip the (?!\b(?:no|none)) test.
- In fact, should '**,no**', '**"none"**' be excluded? this will impact how words are counted. modifying `ptn_to_excluded` could be enough.

Comment: Thanks jxc, this is an interesting approach! However when i've been testing it, it seems to look across the whole text whereas the condition is 'not' or 'none' appearing three words before.

Comment: hi, @avocet. I modified the logic to match the text and check the words before (max 3 words) and do the mapping only when the excluded-words are not seen. the regex actually checks from those excluded-words (if exists) backwards, but should have the same effects. let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi @jxc thanks for this excellent solution! Also for the detailed explanation - very much appreciate your expertise

Answer (score 1):

Starting by creating a dictionary of replaced items will help. You can do the following:

```
# create a dict
make_dict = replace_terms_df.set_index('Text')['Replace_item'].to_dict()

# this function does the replacement work
def g_val(strin, dic):

    d = []
    if 'none' in strin or 'no' in strin:
        return strin
    else:
        for i in strin.split():
            if i not in dic:
                d.append(i)
            else:
                d.append(dic[i])
        return ' '.join(d)

## apply the function
text_df['new_text'] = text_df['Text'].apply(lambda x: g_val(x, dic=make_dict))

## check output
print(text_df['new_text'])

0    <HERE_REPLACED> is <SOME_REPLACED> <RANDOM_REP...
1                       no such random text, none here
2                          more <RANDOM_REPLACED> text
```

**Explanation**

In the function, we are doing: 
1. If the string contains none or no, we return the string as is.
2. If it doesn't contain none or no, we check if the word is available in the dictionary, if yes, we return the replaced value else the existing value.

Comment: But the condition isn't simply if the word 'no' or 'none' is anywhere. it's specifically if those words are within 3 words of the replacement word. This would fail to correctly resolve something like `'No, I should  replace random text here'`

Comment: Thanks for your answer YOLO! However ALollz is correct the term must be within 3 words before the replacement.